# Geoip in prestashop smarty template

Tags: prestashop, geoip, smarty3, prestashop-1.5

I need to work with visitor country code in product.tpl. Is there any prestashop global variable with country code, which I can use in smarty template? If not, where I can add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this first go to `Preferences>>Geolocation` and enable it also download .dat file

after this add this code in `controllers >> front >> ProductController.php` before line 238

```
include_once(_PS_GEOIP_DIR_.'geoipcity.inc');
$gi = geoip_open(realpath(_PS_GEOIP_DIR_.'GeoLiteCity.dat'), GEOIP_STANDARD);
$record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, Tools::getRemoteAddr());
```

add this code in smarty assign around line 260

```
'country_name' => $record->country_name //change country_name to code etc
```

Use `$country_name` in product.tpl where ever you want :)

tested in ps-1.5.6

Answer (score 0):

I used @Raza's code to build it as an override to the FrontController with the purpose to not only display it in product.tpl but on **all shop pages**:

1. in override > classes > controller > create file FrontController.php
2. put following code

   ```
   class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
   { 
       public function initContent()
       {
       parent::initContent();

       include_once(_PS_GEOIP_DIR_.'geoipcity.inc');
       $gi = geoip_open(realpath(_PS_GEOIP_DIR_.'GeoLiteCity.dat'), GEOIP_STANDARD);
       $record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, Tools::getRemoteAddr()); 

       $this->context->smarty->assign('country_name', $record->country_name); //change country_name to code etc

       }
   }
   ```

@Raza: using {$country_name} in the .tpl-file displays the country name allways in English. Any idea how to use the PS's core translations to the country in the active shop language?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

@nortonOn: You could try with id_lang from the cookie, this way, it should display the country name in the shop language.
Should look like : `$country->name[intval($this->context->cookie->id_lang)];`

I hope it will help you :)